# android : mutablelivedata change is not updating the UI

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelivedata

I am using MutableLiveData to store a choice user has made. The value is set from another activity. SO onResume i am calling

```
 myMutableLivedata.value = newvale
```

But this does not update the UI unless i call a invalidateall().

Is this expected behaviour of MutableLiveData

Comment: Where are you setting the value of your `LiveData`, and where are you `Observering` it?

Comment: I am setting it in the on Resume again to reflect the change. I do not observe it explicitly. I have not used mutablelivedata much. How do i observe for the changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `LiveData`, you need to `Observe` the changes.

First, create your `MediatorLiveData`.

```
val liveData = MediatorLiveData<MyItem>()
```

Next, within your Activity/Fragment/Etc, you need to call `.observe`. When the `Observer` is fired, it will have the updated data.

```
liveData.observe(this, Observer { 
    // Update the UI when the data has changed
})
```

And lastly, somewhere else in code, you can update the value of your `LiveData`, and the `Observer` will be notified.

```
// Somewhere else
liveData.value = MyItem("new value")
```